# Problems with LinearLayout, views aren't resembling the preview in Graphical Layout on device

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

So I'm having a problem that is driving me crazy. Knowing the purpose of my app isn't important/relevant so I'll just paste my code from the xml file. The layout is a `RelativeLayout`, but the problem I'm having is inside of this `LinearLayout`.
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_orange"
android:id="@+id/rel_layout" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/component_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/source1"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/component_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/component_1"
        android:src="@drawable/source2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/component_1"
        android:layout_marginRight="-50dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dip"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/problemIsHere"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="What&apos;s your question?"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoComplete"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/source3"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/problemIsHere"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/source4"
        android:onClick="computeUserInput" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/voice_recognition_touse" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, this is nested inside of the parent, `RelativeLayout`. In the preview, when clicking on the "Graphical Layout" tab, this looks like exactly what I want; `EditText` to the left of a small `ImageButton`, with correct proportions and margins. However, when I run this on my device, the `LinearLayout` is REVERSED, meaning now that the `EditText` is to the RIGHT of the `ImageButton`. The proportions and margins are still accurate though. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Note: I've already cleaned and refreshed my project; this was ineffective. I've also tried removing the `layout_gravity` attributes, and that did nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire XML.  The parents attributes are important in figuring this out.

Comment: Just added it, I renamed all the ID's and source names, the linear layout that is relevant is the one with the ID "problemIsHere"